Category of Sets vs Category of Types (& Yoneda Lemma)
I've been wondering for a while why we discuss the category of sets, $\mathbf{Set}$, all the time, but hardly discuss something like the category of all types and functions between them ($\mathbf{Type}$, maybe), obviously depending on whatever which type theory you're discussing.
Is it because this category just turns out to be equivalent or isomorphic to $\mathbf{Set}$, or is it just not interesting?
Is the Lawvere ETCS formulation of the category $\mathbf{Set}$ as a well-pointed topos with a natural number object equivalent to some category like $\mathbf{Type}$ as well?
If they are not equivalent, what is so significant $\mathbf{Set}$, anyway? Is there something special about it that makes it the only relevant category to formulate things like presheaves? What about the Yoneda Lemma, could that be equally given in terms of another $\mathbf{Set}$-like category, like a topos?
For example, does the Yoneda Lemma need some sort of axiom of choice in the $\mathbf{Set}$-like target category specifically to function, making it so the target category must be functionally equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$ anyway?

Sorry for the multiple questions, I guess I'm very unclear about the significance of the category $\mathbf{Set}$ in category theory over other categories.
Let me ask more specifically:

Why do we not discuss categories like $\mathbf{Type}$ (above)?
Is the category $\mathbf{Set}$ the only category appropriate to formulate the notion that every category can be embedded in its category of of functors to sets? (Yoneda)
And does this not equally work with some type theoretic foundations instead?


As you said, the precise definition of "$\mathbf{Type}$" depends on which type theory we're discussing; more importantly, it also depends on whether you take an external or an internal perspective.
Externally, that is, from the point of view of the metatheory, type theory itself can be considered as the object of study. You can define a category whose objects are the types (or more generally, contexts) of the type theory and whose objects are the terms (or more generally, substitutions), with the rules of the type theory ensuring that this defines a category. This is the syntactic category, or "term model". Additional structure in the type theory (e.g. product types) corresponds to additional structure in the syntactic category (e.g. products).
Internally, it is possible to work in a type theory that is rich enough to be considered as a foundation for mathematics: say, for example, homotopy type theory / univalent foundations. There, a set (or h-set) is defined as a type with a side condition that ensures that its identity types behave like the usual equality relation in a set. You can then define the category of sets, $\mathbf{Set}$, whose type of objects is the universe of sets $\Sigma_{X : \mathcal{U}} \mathrm{isSet}\ X$ and whose set of morphisms between $X$ and $Y$ is the type of functions $X \to Y$ (which is an h-set since $X$ and $Y$ are). This category behaves very much like the traditional category of sets (see the HoTT book, §§ 9.1, 10.1).
(As a technical aside, note that this category $\mathbf{Set}$ is not the category of all types and functions: a category has a set (in the homotopical sense) of morphisms between any two objects, but the functions between two arbitrary types do not form a set. There are ways to remedy this: you can define the homotopy category of types by set-truncating the types of morphisms (HoTT book 9.1.18), or you can remove the condition that the morphisms form a set (obtaining the notion of wild category), but these are not very well-behaved objects. Alternatively, if you trade univalence for the uniqueness of identity proofs, then every type is a set so you can form the category of all types and functions.)
To summarise and answer your questions,

We do talk about categories of types externally, when studying the properties of type theories. When formalising the category of sets internally to type theory, we just call it the category of sets.
Indeed, the category of sets is special in that it is in a sense part of the definition of a category ($\mathrm{Hom}$-sets); however, it is possible to generalise this definition to have $\mathrm{Hom}$-objects living in a different category: this is the world of enriched category theory, which comes with its own enriched Yoneda lemma.
It does; as outlined above, HoTT/UF provides a type-theoretic foundation for mathematics in which one can talk about the usual category of sets. Note that these are constructive foundations: you do not need any form of the axiom of choice (or even excluded middle) to talk about the Yoneda lemma.

